# How to change the content of a gwt panel?

Tags: gwt, widget

Assume I have a view named A and its xml is something like:

```
<g:HTMLPanel>
  <my:widgetA>
    ....
  </my:widgetA>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

Also, I have another widget named widgetB. I'd like to change the content of view A based on some condition, like:

```
if (...is true) {
   A.clear();
   A.add(widgetA);
} else {
   A.clear();
   A.add(widgetB);
}
```

Now the problem is view A cannot display widgetA correctly. View A becomes blank when adding widgetA into it. What's the problem with the implementation above?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code. The problem is somewhere else. Examine the HTML in your browser to see why widget A is not visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be adding a widget, that implements [RequiresResize](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/RequiresResize.html) or at least needs to be given a fixed size.

To find out if that is the case, just call [setSize](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/UIObject.html#setSize(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)) on that widget with a fixed size like that: `widgetA.setSize('50px','50px);'`

If that works, you either need to provide a size or use a panel, which implements [ProvidesResize](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ProvidesResize.html).